# Can a RowLayout item have signals in QML?

Tags: qt, qml, signals, signals-slots

I'm having a little problem with some custom Items I'm using im my QML code. I created a set of Items consisting in a RowLayout containing a label and an input control (e.g. SpinBox or ComboBox). In order to "bring the value changed signal outside" i added to the external RowLayout a signal that should be emitted onValueChanged. Here's the code:

```
import QtQuick 2.10
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

RowLayout {
    property alias label: innerLabel.text
    property alias value: innerNum.value
    property alias editable: innerNum.editable
    property alias min: innerNum.from
    property alias max: innerNum.to
    property string myPage: ""
    property string myMeasure: ""
    property int fontSize: 16
    property bool signaling: true
    property var colorAccent: Material.accent
    property var colorPrimary: Material.primary
    signal fabValueChanged(var message)

    Label{
        id: innerLabel
        Layout.fillHeight: filling
        Layout.fillWidth: filling
        Material.foreground: colorAccent
        font.pixelSize: fontSize
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
        property bool filling: true
        onTextChanged: function(){
            if (text == ""){
                filling = false;
                width = 0;
            }
            else{
                filling = true;
            }
        }
    }

    SpinBox{
        id: innerNum
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Material.foreground: colorAccent
        editable: true
        to: 100000
        from: 1
        value: 1
        onValueChanged: function(){
            if(parent.signaling){
                var toSend = {"name":parent.objectName,"value":value,"measure":parent.myMeasure};
                fabValueChanged(toSend);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I connect the fabValueChanged to a simple slot that just prints the message I got nothing, even if the onValueChanged signal is correctly emitted.
Can it be that RowLayout cannot emit signals? If that's the case, How can I modify my object in order to avoid this problem?
If my problem is not the layout, wht is going on?

Comment: Are you sure the `onValueChanged` handler is called? Try adding a `console.log(...)` there as well. But in the end I think you need to connect to `onValueModified`. (and BTW, you also can leave `function()`)

Comment: I advice you to check in debugger that `onValueChanged()` called and that it calls `fabValueChanged()`. Also, as already @Amfasis noticed I would replace `onEvent: function(){}` with `onEvent: {}`

Comment: In the end the problem was not in the element but in the function I used to dynamically create these objects. I'm really sorry for waisting your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really rossy for waistin other people's time on this issue. In the end the problem was with the function I used to dynamically create these objects. So the object as it is can emit signal without any problem.

Sorry again